# Textbox hit function on Enter button

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I have a mvc3 application. and on one page i have a textbox that will allow a user to search for a client, now i am struggling with some functionality, as i am a windows form and widows phone 8 developer. i want this text box i have here to execute as i press enter, i have a button that the user can click on to search, but i know most users just click enter! i am using JavaScript to hit function!

Html for button and textbox:

```
    <td>
<input value="Search..." id="SearchText" style="color:GrayText" onchange="SearchText" onfocus="javascript:this.value=''" onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='Search...';}" />
                        <input id="searchbutton" type="button"  value="Search" class="button"/>
                    </td>
```

Here is the Javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $('#searchbutton').click(function(){
                var client = document.getElementById('SearchText').value;
                var textbox = document.getElementById('SearchText');
                var edittext = ", is not available!";
                var result = client + edittext;

                if (textbox.value == 'Search...') {
                    alert('Please enter a Client Name to search for ');
                    textbox.focus();
                }
                else {
                    alert(result);
                };


            });


        </script>
```

how would i get the textbox to also trigger the function as i hit enter on the textbox!

here is how it looks on the form :

[image]

very new to this kind of coding, any help will do!

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#searchbutton').click(search);
$('#SearchText').keypress(function(e){
     var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
      if(code == 13) {
        search()
      }
});


function search(){
    var client = document.getElementById('SearchText').value;
            var textbox = document.getElementById('SearchText');
            var edittext = ", is not available!";
            var result = client + edittext;

            if (textbox.value == 'Search...') {
                alert('Please enter a Client Name to search for ');
                textbox.focus();
            }
            else {
                alert(result);
            };
}
```

Comment: Thanks A Lot!... this worked awesome, cant believe it is so easy! thanks Karaxuna

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#SearchText').on('keypress', function(e){

    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
             if(code == 13) {
             //write your code for search here..like searchbutton on click
             }
    });
```

Comment: maybe `e.preventDefault()` could be also needed.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know the exact answer to your question but you could use a [tabindex](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TABINDEX.html)
to press tab to jump to your button and then you can press enter to submit.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="txtSearch"  />
<input type="button" value="Search" id="btnsearch" onclick="return Search();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#txtSearch").keyup(function (event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $("#btnsearch").click();
        }
    });

    function Search(){
             // do Something here.......
     }

</script>
```